# How can i read only third line from a file into a variable in shell script

Tags: shell

I am executing a shell script in which I run a sybase query which gives the O/P in a file .

The Output is :-

```
            tablename

            ---------------------------
            result of query executed my case will be an integer returned


            (Number of rows effected ).
```

What i want to do is read `result of query executed which in my case will be an integer returned` into a variable in a shell script . It will be in 3rd line in the file in which i have redirected the Output of my Sybase Query .

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
x=`sed -n '3p' inputfile`;
echo $x;
```

EDIT

Do this.

```
thirdline=`sed -n '3p' /home/nmsad/abc.txt`;
echo $thirdline;
```

Comment: yeah .. i guess I needed this only .

Comment: In case the input is huge, `sed -n '3{p;q}'`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sed` like this:

```
variable=$(your_script | sed -n '3 p')
```

Comment: actually inside the script I have written the sybase Query Which gives me a result in say file /home/nmsad/abc.txt in which i need to extract the third line which i need to pass to my variable

Answer (score 2):

add this line in your script

```
cat youroutputfile|awk 'NR==3' >new_outputfile
```

Comment: In case the input is huge: `awk 'NR==3 {print; exit}'`

Answer (score 1):

This worked well for me:

```
thirdline=$(sed -n '3p' filename)
```

Then run `echo $thirdline`